# Generic method showing compile time error in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with signature in a class named **ProductServiceFactory** :

```
  public <T> T processRequest(T request, final String value) {
     //Implementation
 }
```

I am trying to pass different types or **request** objects like this :

```
new ProductServiceFactory().processRequest(request, ApplicationConstants.DATA_SUBSCRIPTION);
```

I don't know why but I am getting compile time error at **request**.

Error Message is :

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found : "SubscriptionRequest" required "T".
```

Since it is a generic method, my understanding is it would accept any type or request object.

Comment: Could you specify what is the type of your request variable and how do you use the result of processRequest call?

Comment: You also return an object of the same type that the first input param, is it correct?